# Upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and I can't open Chrome in Activities

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04

Just updated to 22.04, but I'm having an issue where I can't open Google Chrome via the Activities search bar. I purged and reinstalled it, and I can open it from Terminal, but not via Activities which is a problem because I can't pin it to Favorites.

Has anyone figured out a solution for this?

Comment: `snap list` -> chrome shown? As snap:s are "contained", this might be the reason why it doesn't show up in activities. My guess!

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact issue on upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04. It turns out that I had an old google-chrome .desktop file lurking in /home/user/.local/share/applications/. Deleting that .desktop caused google-chrome to immediately appear in the app search and become favorite-able.

Comment: thanks for the post. i tried your suggestion, removing the .desktop file from /home/%user%/.local/share/applications/ allowed me to add to favorites, but deleting it from /usr/share/applications/ will cause it not to stay on the favorites. so you definitely need it there. issue still is that it(icon) doesn't come up in search? even after reinstalling through different methods...apt, dpkg, gdebi...etc.

Comment: That is a good point. I didn't actually check /usr/share/applications/ first, and I should have. I've edited the answer so I don't steer anyone wrong.